# How to make scrollable LazyRow with paging 3 with full width

Tags: android, scroll, pagination, paging

How to show on screen the first element not the last?

```
val pages = viewModel.getPages().collectAsLazyPagingItems()
LazyRow {
        items(
            items = pages,
            key = { it.id }
        ) { page ->
            Card(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillParentMaxWidth()
            ) {

        }
    }
```

items = pages has three elements,
but the card shows on screen the last element ( nextKey ) and I need to scroll one element back to see the element which was clicked.
//paging source

```
override suspend fun load(params: LoadParams<Int>): LoadResult<Int, Page> {
        return 
            println(params.key)
            val page = params.key ?: 1

            val response = repository.getPage(
                account = account,
                maxlen = maxlen
            )
            LoadResult.Page(
                data = response,
                prevKey = page.minus(1),
                nextKey = if (response.isEmpty()) null else page.plus(1),
            )
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I need this inside LazyRow:

```
val lazyListState = rememberLazyListState()
coroutineScope.launch {
    lazyListState.animateScrollToItem(index = 1)
}
```